# tomcat className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" real example?

Tags: java, tomcat

1.I came across documentation on this, but cannot find real examples on how to use it? Any tutorial on this?
2. Is there any sample .war that I can try out on this?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html), scroll down to "Single Sign On" section.

You can try it with any web applications that have authentication configured. All you need to do is to enable (or add)

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" debug="0"/>
```

in Tomcat's server.xml (it's commented out by default) AND have realm specified at the host level (e.g. within that same server.xml) as opposed to individual application context.

Comment: i alr read the doc.
1.does both web app need to have asme authentication configured? mean if webapp 1 using database authentication with email as username, 2nd webapp must use same method ?
2. how to specify realm. can elaborate?

Comment: 1. All applications for which you want Single Sign On to work must share the same realm, so yes - authentication mechanism will be exactly the same. 2. Realm should be specified within the same `<Host>` element as SingleSignOn valve. Details are here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/realm-howto.html. 
For db-based authentication you're looking at JDBCRealm, there's an example in the above link.